# How can I add a column to a set of grouped columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

Suppose I have this query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tab1
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1    -- **************EDIT****************
```

I want that set of columns to be unique. But, now I want to add col4, which can be duplicated, so it doesn't work if I add it and group it.

Is there a better way to do it than this in SQL Server 2008 R2?

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4
FROM (
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM tab1
    GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 -- **************EDIT****************
    ) a JOIN tab1 b 
ON a.col1 = b.col1
AND a.col2 = b.col2
AND a.col3 = b.col3
```

**EDIT:** Sorry guys, this is what I was looking for. You were right for the query I posted at first, a simple SELECT would do it. What I need is to show all the values of `col4`, for each distinct group of `col1, col2, col3`, when duplicates exist.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is technically different than what you're requesting, but it may satisfy your requirements.

If you select all four columns, group by all four, and select COUNT(*), then the count represents only the number of times that the fourth column occurs for each subset of the other three.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, COUNT(*) AS c
FROM tab1
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4
```

For example, if your results are ['JIM', 'JOE', 'BOB', 'BILLY', 5], it means you have 5 Billies for every Jim Joe Bob in the trailer park.

EDIT:

Try this, as per my last comment.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM tab1
```

Comment: *"But, now I want to add col4, which can be duplicated, so it doesn't work if I add it and group it."* You can't include `col4` in the group as the OP specifically is asking to see the **detail** of all `col4` values.

Comment: Yeah, I read the word "duplicated" as meaning "duplicated", not "unique".  My bad...

Comment: The thing is I need to insert in a table with a unique index on col1, col2, col3. That's why I need those unique, but col4 can have whatever values (0+)

Comment: So it sounds like you just want to select those 4 columns without any grouping.

Comment: Well, I think you are right, actually. But in the "real" query I have, I don't get same results using just the SELECT vs the first query I posted. It might be because nested views... let me check.

Comment: You were definitely right, +1. But I was looking for another thing, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it seems ok to me. But you can also try `SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab1` in your derived table instead of `SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM tab1 GROUP BY col1, col2, col3`. I'm not sure if it makes any difference in execution plan though.

Also, I might misunderstand what you are trying to achieve, but it looks like result of your query will be the same as just `SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, a.col4 FROM table1 a`

Comment: I'm probably missing something,but doesn't just `SELECT a.col1, a.col2, a.col3, b.col4 FROM table1` return the same ?

Comment: Well, now I think you are right, actually. But in the "real" query I have, I don't get same results using just the SELECT vs the first query I posted. It might be because nested views... let me check.

Comment: @olmed0: I think you need to post the actual query (or something that illustrates a problem better ) .

Comment: Like I said, there are several nested views, quite long... I can't post the actual query but I will try to see what's wrong with it and let you know.

Comment: You were right, +1. But I was looking for something different (check EDIT), my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CTE, but there's nothing at all wrong with your method:

```
WITH G AS (
  SELECT col1, col2, col3
  FROM tab1
  GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
)
SELECT G.col1, G.col2, G.col3, b.col4
FROM G JOIN tab1 b 
         ON G.col1 = b.col1
        AND G.col2 = b.col2
        AND G.col3 = b.col3;
```

Comment: Same cost in execution plan :(

Comment: @olmed0 Right, I don't think you're really going to get around that. The problem involves defining the group, and then referencing the group to get its detail. It can be made less complex if your group has a unique ID, but the logic remains the same.

Comment: OK, thanks. I was just wondering if I was missing some function that would do the trick here.